Max number of walks to a goal vertex, each with different starting vertex
I want to solve the following problem:
Given an undirected graph $G$ with positive integer weights, find maximum number of walks (each with different starting vertices) that ends at some specified vertex $v$, and the total number of times one travels through an edge in all these walks can't exceed the edge's weight. The time bound is $O(m^2)$, where $m$ is number of edges of $G$.
For example, if an edge has weight 2, then at most 2 different walks can use it as part of the walk. If a walk use this edge twice, then no other walks can use it. We can view it as decreasing the edge's weight by 1 every time one uses this edge in a walk. We keep finding walks and decrease the edges' weights, starting from a new (we can pick) starting vertex in a new walk, until there's no walk from any vertex to the specified end vertex.
My attempt:
The problem was originally phrased in terms of bridges and islands, so formalizing it into a graph problem is already a part of my attempt. One other idea I have is that all walks must just be simple paths, since cycles are useless to what we want to do. The problem feels somewhat like the max flow problem (although we don't have same starting vertex in this problem, and the graph is undirected rather than directed), but I'm not sure how exactly to relate them.
